# What weather improves which types?

Tags: pokemon-go

Since the last update, different real life weather types have an influence on the attack and spawn rate of certain types. For example, rain will boosts water types, so what other combinations are there?

Answer (score 7):

The following weather types are implemented, with all possible types being present exactly once:

- **Fog** Dark, Ghost
- **Clear/Sun** Grass, Ground, Fire
- **Snow** Ice, Steel
- **Rain** Water, Bug, Electric
- **Wind** Dragon, Flying,Psychic
- **Partly Cloudy** Normal, Rock
- **Cloudy** Fairy, Fighting, Poison

Your current weather is shown in the lower right, above the nearby Pokémon view.

Comment: For completeness: There's also "Extreme", which boosts nothing and comes with a warning not to go outside.

Comment: There's also Cloudy which boosts Fairy, Fighting and Poison types.